# What is a new biotechnology issue?

Tags: biochemistry, biotechnology

I'm looking for any new biotechnology issue related to Biochemistry, Metabolic processes, molecular Genetics, or other relevant fields. If anyone knows of an issue that has solid resources around I'd love to hear all about it.

Comment: You use the term 'biotechnology' in a wrong way. It is a field of science and is somewhat mixture of what you've listed. I don't know what you're looking for, so could you pleas clarify what you mean by biotechnology? I'm voting for close this question as 'unclear what you're asking', that I'm willing to retract.

Comment: Edited, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: It makes more sense, yet it is till unclear and / or too broad. There are tons of biotechnology papers, journals, full of research. Interesting to who? For eg. plant biotech. is could be interesting to someone (for eg. you), but I'm totally uninterested in it right now. Interesting at what level? For an average person beer and champagne production can be interesting ( it is a sort of biotechnology)....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Biotechnology is a **gigantic field**. You should have a look at the wikipedia entry for [biotechnology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biotechnology).

Because of the size of the field "biotechnology", because the word biotechnology accept different definitions and because the word interesting is extremely arbitrary it is pretty much impossible to give a good answer to this question.

I am using below wikipedia's definiton of biotechnology that encompass...pretty much everything! The wiki definition include fields such as:

- chemical and bioprocess engineering
- bioinformatics and biostatistics
- biorobotics

From @poka.nando's comment, the UN definition is 
Hoping it will help you, below are few random examples of research in biotechnology: "Biotechnology is the use of living systems and organisms to develop or make products, or "any technological application that uses biological systems, living organisms or derivatives thereof, to make or modify products or processes for specific use" (UN Convention on Biological Diversity, Art. 2)" Under this definition fields such as bioinformatics would probably not really fit within the field of biotechnology.

Using wiki's definition of biotechnology below are few examples of s^hitngs you might be looking for.

- Improve the statistical tools to detect differential selection pressure in a phylogeny (methods such as [PAML](http://abacus.gene.ucl.ac.uk/software/paml.html))
- Improving [fungiculture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungiculture) by improving our understanding of the mushroom life cycle variation in response to temperature.
- Track down genes of resistance to drought in tomato ([GWAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome-wide_association_study))
- Design better [artificial hearts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_heart) or get a better understanding of [cell differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_differentiation) in order to be able to rebuild lost tissues or even organs (see [regenerative medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_medicine)).
- Improve understanding of the transmission of the [African swine fever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_swine_fever_virus) in order to improve its use as a [biological warfare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_warfare).

Comment: I think we have different understanding of biotechnology : "Biotechnology is the use of living systems and organisms to develop or make products, or "any technological application that uses biological systems, living organisms or derivatives thereof, to make or modify products or processes for specific use" (UN Convention on Biological Diversity, Art. 2)" taken from wikipedia, an basically this is what I was taught under biotech.

Comment: I am using wikipedia's definition which also include bioinformatics and this kind of tools. Let me update my answer with your comment in mind.

Comment: The very page you link list quite different fields and to make it clear: 
"In many instances, it is also dependent on knowledge and methods from outside the sphere of biology including:

    bioinformatics, a new brand of computer science
    bioprocess engineering
    biorobotics
    chemical engineering
" I think you copied the wrong part...

Comment: Oops you're right.... ok. I got lazy to work for a poorly defined question. I vote for closing! Hum... I can't delete my answer as it has been accepted now!